# VBA Trying to print values into the last row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this code (in conjunction with code that calculates the variables using ranges in a different sheet - these calculations are working perfectly). I'm then using this "with statement" to swap to the sheet I want to print the values into.

I'm trying to print the values into the first blank row (I've checked and the row is blank). However, no information is filling out into the cells - they remain blank.

```
 With Sheets("Reconciliation")
                            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = E
                            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Str
                            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Min
                            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Max
                            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = Sea
                            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = Mat
                        End With
```

Comment: put a `.` in front of each the `Range(...`

Comment: And to be thorough, in front of each `Rows` too.

Comment: Also are you sure all columns have the same number of rows. If so, you don't need to re-calculate each time.

Comment: That worked! So simple - thanks. @ScottCraner Do either of you have any experience with your code running properly when you step through in slowly in F8 but breaking when you hold down F8 or just hit run?

Comment: Is column "E" missing?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for your help - do you have any experience with the above issue of the code breaking when you hit run but working in F8

Comment: @PPP - This happens when your code depends on `ActiveSheet` which might be different with [F8] vs. run. Anytime you have a `Range()` or `Cells()` you need to qualify it with the worksheet reference in front of it.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I've just changed the above code a bit - realised I pasted in the wrong section. However, are you suggesting I could do `.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up)` and then have `.Offset(1,0).Value=E` and `.Offset(0,1).Value = Str` ect.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I don't have any select or activesheet in this sub (I do in other subs before I learnt how to use range properly)

Comment: The code is incorrect above. Each `.Offset()` is not relative to the previous statement, but to what comes before it.

Comment: @PPP The problem is the `Rows.Count` it needs to be `.Rows.Count`. Ortherwise it implies  `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou More information: even though there are no select or activecell in this sub the code is not working unless a cell in the correct sheet is selected - is there a nuance of the "with" function that I am using incorrectly?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou It Worked!!! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: When you are typing `Range()` it implies `ActiveSheet.Range()`. In a With statement you need to use `.Range()`  with emphasis on the **.** in front of Range to imply `Sheets().Range()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for simplicity:

```
Dim lastRow as Long
With Sheets("Reconciliation")
    lastRow = .Range("A1").Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1").Cells(lastRow+1,1).Value = E
    .Range("A1").Cells(lastRow+1,2).Value = Str
    .Range("A1").Cells(lastRow+1,3).Value = Min
    .Range("A1").Cells(lastRow+1,4).Value = Max
    .Range("A1").Cells(lastRow+1,6).Value = Sea
    .Range("A1").Cells(lastRow+1,7).Value = Mat
End With
```

Comment: @PPP Please check the code above if it works for you.